# subscribe to control's events in VBA

Tags: events, vba, combobox

How do you subsribe to control's events in VBA? I am using MS Word 2010. I can see the public properties of the control in the properties window (F4), but I don't see any events there or an events window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you mean events for controls on a userform; In the code editing window there are 2 combo-boxes at the very top, pick the control name from the left one and the event from the right and it will create a stub for you.